# YouTube API. Validate Refresh Token before Upload

Tags: c#, youtube-api, google-oauth, access-token

I am using the following code to get authoriziation and upload to YouTube:

I have requested my token from google and the user has logged in and I have got my authorization token back.

I have exchanged this for a refresh and access token using the following:

```
 using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {

                byte[] response =
                    client.UploadValues("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", new NameValueCollection()
                        {
                            {"code", Session["authCode"].ToString()},
                            {"redirect_uri", "http://YouTubeTest.org/testpage.aspx"},
                            {
                                "client_id", clientID
                            },
                            {"client_secret", secret},
                            {"grant_type", "authorization_code"}
                        });


                string result =Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
                XElement node = XElement.Parse(JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(result, "Root").ToString());
                Session["refreshtoken"] = node.Element("refresh_token").Value;
            }
```

These details are then stored.

When a user clicks to upload a video I initialise the youtube service as follows:

```
 ClientSecrets secrets = new ClientSecrets()
            {
                ClientId = CLIENT_ID,
                ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET
            };

            var token = new TokenResponse { RefreshToken = REFRESH_TOKEN };

            var credentials = new UserCredential(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = secrets
                }),
                "user",
                token);

            var service = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
                ApplicationName = "TestProject"
            });
```

At this point I would like to know if the refresh token I have sent over is valid, but there doesn't seem to be any way of telling.

The only way I seem to know is when I actually try and upload a video by doing the following:

```
public String UploadVideo(Stream stream, String title, String desc, String[] tags, String categoryId, Boolean isPublic)
        {
            var video = new Video();
            video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            video.Snippet.Title = title;
            video.Snippet.Description = desc;
            video.Snippet.Tags = tags;
            video.Snippet.CategoryId = categoryId; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
            video.Status = new VideoStatus();
            video.Status.PrivacyStatus = isPublic ? "public" : "private";


            var videosInsertRequest = youtube.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", stream, "video/*");
            videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += insertRequest_ProgressChanged;
            videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += insertRequest_ResponseReceived;
            videosInsertRequest.Upload();

            return UploadedVideoId;
        }

  void insertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
        {
            UploadedVideoId = video.Id;
      }

        void insertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
        {
            // You can handle several status messages here.
            switch (progress.Status)
            {
                case UploadStatus.Failed:
                    UploadedVideoId = "FAILED";
```

**^^ If the token is invalid at this point the progress has an exception with "Invalid_grant"**

```
                    break;
                case UploadStatus.Completed:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

**How do I find out before I try an upload if the refresh token I have is valid?**

It's difficult to recover nicely from it at this point, so ideally I'd like to be able to check it when or after I initialize the youtube service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validating a token is part of the [Google Identity](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#validatetoken) documentation. It suggests that you can validate a token by requesting in a web service endpoint.

You can call `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo` along with your `access_token` as a parameter

> https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3Zg

The response will have a JSON object that describes the token or an error. More details about this can be found on the referenced page in the documentation above.